# All Images inline with overflow

Tags: css

First container fine, u can see 2 images and there are 6 images with overflow. (vertical)

Container2 problem, I want to make horizontal images list with overflow (Only x / horizontal).

My css so far:

```
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40vw;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#imglist {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40%;
}

#imglist div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#imglist div img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*Problem*/

#container2 {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20vw;
  background: red;
}

#imglist2 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vw;
}

#imglist2 div {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
```

Example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4a2tc7s/

Comment: Add  'white-space: nowrap;'  to #container2 https://jsfiddle.net/n4a2tc7s/1/

Comment: Did any of these answers helped you?

Answer (score 2):

### Explicitly control wrapping and hiding

In addition to defining `white-space: nowrap` on the container, you should explicitly define `overflow-y: hidden` instead of `overflow-x: scroll`. Scroll bars will automatically appear on overflowed containers (unless you already have a rule preventing them), so you need only to restrict the scroll bars on the `y` axis for your scenario.

In the following example, I also set `height: 100%` on `#imglist2` because the `15vw` declaration was causing the scrollbar to crop the images. If that was intentional, feel free to roll it back in:

```css
#container2 {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20vw;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#imglist2 {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
/*height: 15vw;*/
  height: 100%;
}

#imglist2 div {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="container2">
  <div id="imglist2">
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Je7VuV9yHIw/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/uxps_fYUeJk/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Zvr3cwbbqHU/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ka9xtXPD3BA/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/U8HVQXkeU8U/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/e7_UUfokexM/1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
#container2 {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20vw;
    background: red;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```